# Installing Epson Stylus SX115 printer on Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, printing

I have a printer 'Epson Stylus Sx115' plugged into my USB port.

It is detected because it is listed in `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8507 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 04b8:084d Seiko Epson Corp. Stylus SX115
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:0221 Apple, Inc. Aluminum Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:0304 Apple, Inc. Optical USB Mouse [Mitsumi]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. IR Receiver [built-in]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:0237 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ISO)
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 05ac:8213 Apple, Inc.
```

I have CUPS installed as well as Gutenprint and the Epson driver from Avasys.

However, when adding a new printer CUPS does not detect it so I can't install it.

CUPS seems to be working because it is detecting my network printer (Brother DCP).

How can I install my Epson printer?

PS: I tried disabling the `usblp` module but without result.

Comment: Do you see it when *executing* `/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb`, too?  (That's what CUPS sees.)

Comment: @sr_
/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb

DEBUG: list_devices
DEBUG: usb_find_busses=4
DEBUG: usb_find_devices=14

Comment: What does `dmesg` say when you plug it in?

Comment: @kevin
[61661.720628] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[61661.946785] WARNING! power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead
[61662.068668] usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04B8 pid 0x084D
[61662.068698] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this problem by following this wiki page instructions
[ArchLinux Wiki CUPS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Blacklisting_usblp)

Basically you need to install cups ghostscript gsfont from pacman and [this](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=39015) epson driver from AUR and then follow the [USB printers under CUPS 1.4.x](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#USB_printers_under_CUPS_1.4.x) section instructions.